# PHP group array by two keys and get total

Tags: php, arrays, summary

I have long arrays (could be hundreds) from `$_POST` and need to summarize the qty.

Below is the `$_POST` result:

```
array(5) {
  ["Batch_No"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "AAAV343"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "AAAV343"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "AAAV347"
  }
  ["Expire"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["Prod_ID"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "00041"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "00041"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "00041"
  }
  ["zID_Line"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "17"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "17"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "17"
  }
  ["Qty"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

I need to summarize the array using **Batch_No** and **Prod_ID**, so that the result would be become like this:

```
array(5) {
  ["Batch_No"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "AAAV343"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "AAAV347"
  }
  ["Expire"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["Prod_ID"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "00041"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "00041"
  }
  ["zID_Line"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "17"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "17"
  }
  ["Qty"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

The `Qty` is basically the TOTAL of each array which has identical `Batch_No` AND `Prod_ID`.

Been trying to explore existing topics, but cannot resolve the issues due to those two keys.

Comment: Show the code that you've been trying.

Comment: You're struggling with this because you have a datastructure issue, not really a code one, though you may be in a situation where there's little you can do about that. You'll probably save time, and definitely make things easier on future devs, if your form is nicely formatted so batches  are unique and contain their own properties. This is one case where a few minutes of client-side work (e.g. submitting this as JSON data, or better-organizing the form inputs so batches contain their properties) will save you hours of doing things the wrong-way server side.

Comment: My goal was actually to avoid traveling to database, but I guess this is a bit _push the limit_. I agree there are other ways of doing this correctly. And yes, it is much easier doing this grouping by using the database. Simply `GROUP BY Prod_ID, Batch_No` and `SUM(Qty_SPTB) AS Qty_Total`, issue solved! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not totally clear to me what you mean by "summarize the array using Batch_No and Prod_ID": I see no 'uniqueness' in the Prod_ID. Hoewever, the following code will create an array (`$totals`) with only unique `'Batch_No'`'s and for those, all (first) matching values of `Expire`, `Prod_ID` and `zID_Line`, and the sum of the `Qty`'s.

```
$totals = array(
    'Batch_No' => array(),
    'Expire' => array(),
    'Prod_ID' => array(),
    'zID_Line' => array(),
    'Qty' => array(),
);
foreach($_POST['Batch_No'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($key2 = array_search($value, $totals['Batch_No'])) {
        $totals['Qty'][$key2] += $_POST['Qty'][$key];
    } else {
        $totals['Batch_No'][] = $_POST['Batch_No'][$key];
        $totals['Expire'][]   = $_POST['Expire'][$key];
        $totals['Prod_ID'][]  = $_POST['Prod_ID'][$key];
        $totals['zID_Line'][] = $_POST['zID_Line'][$key];
        $totals['Qty'][]      = $_POST['Qty'][$key];
    }
}
```

It works by iterating over the POST values. For every value found in `Batch_No`, it tries to find it in `$totals`. If it is not there, add it. If it is there already, leave most values alone, but add the quantity found in `Qty` to the quantity already stored.

Comment: Hi @marten-koetsier, you are right, my sample arrays don't show the uniqueness of Prod_ID, but in reality there will be hundreds of Prod_ID with vary Batch_No to group with. Your code works well as long as for Batch_No key. Thanks.

Anyhow, after over-a-night of sleep (I guess that's all I need), I realize that this is a bit _push the limit_. I agree with @josh-from-qaribou, there are other ways of doing this correctly. And yes, it is much easier doing this grouping by using the database. Simply `GROUP BY Prod_ID, Batch_No` and `SUM(Qty_SPTB) AS Qty_Total`, issue solved! Thanks everyone.